# Can the default size of Windows 7's "drag to the left or right to resize window" feature be changed?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

Windows 7 includes a feature for easily arranging windows on larger monitors - drag a window to the left or right side of the screen and it will be resized to use half the monitor (or drag to the top to maximize). The most obvious use of this is to drag one window to the left and one to the right to quickly get 2 side by side windows.

My question is, even on a 1920x1200 screen the width of a split window is not enough for many applications - in particular web pages tend to be designed for 1024x768 and up. Is there a way (registry?) to change the split between left and right? So that a window dragged to the left will be resized to 60% of the screen, and one to the right will occupy 40%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program called WinSplit Revolution that will allow you to move and resize windows with preset sizes. You use hotkeys to move them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for about 30 minutes but everything I've found points to it being a hard-coded ratio within windows. I did find this setting in the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

Snap Sizing. Mine is set to 1.

Not sure what it does but, since it's binary, I'd assume 1 is on and 0 is off. You may want to set it to 0, save, use Aero Snap, resize your windows, close and reopen to see if they 'remember' the previous size.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/56312-how-change-default-window-size.html

"Hi lavecoi,

You can resize dialog boxes by click-and-dragging the textured area in the lower right corner of the window. Unfortunately there's no way to set a default size for dialog boxes, although your resizings will be remembered on a per-application basis between restarts.

Hope this was helpful...

Cheers,

Walker
Windows Outreach Team"